# ReactJs unmount component on update

Tags: reactjs

I would like to unmount a component when is updated this.state.data == false

so I wrote

```
componentDidUpdate: function() {
    var el = React.findDOMNode(this);
    if(this.state.data == false) {
        React.unmountComponentAtNode(el);
    }
}
```

But it's not working React.unmountComponentAtNode(el) return false. The idea is that if there is no data the former component (which had some data) is destroyed/unmount.

Obviously this is not the right way to do but I don't know what to do. I don't understand why it returns false.

thanks for your help

Comment: Generally, you'd do this by raising an event to the parent container and the parent container would re-render the children, leaving this specific child out during the next `render` pass.

Comment: how to leave the specific child out during the next render ?

Comment: An `if` would be fine. http://facebook.github.io/react/tips/if-else-in-JSX.html

Comment: ok I thought it was dirty to do it this way. I started with this solution then changed then... Just make it simple :) thanks !

Comment: Not a bad solution at all. In fact, very typical.